# What if we only have one reducer

Tags: hadoop

As we know that Hadoop tend to lanunch reducer on the machines that the corresponding mapper is run. What if we have 100 mappers and 1 reducer. We know that the mapper stores data on local disk ,will all the mapped data be transfered to the single reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the reducer is only one, all the data will be transferred to that reducer.

Each mapper initially stores its output in its local buffer(100mb default), and when the buffer is filled to a certain percentage defined by **io.sort.spill.percent**, the result will be spilled on to disk defined by **mapred.local.dir**.

These files are copied on to the reducer during **copy phase**, in which output of each mapper is copied by **mapred.reduce.parallel.copies** parallel threads.(default 5)

Answer (score 0):

If you fix reducer number to one (by job.setNumReduceTasks(1) or -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1) then all data from mappers will be transferred to one reducer that will process all keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 reducer then all the data get tranferred to that reducer and all the output will be stored in HDFS as a single file.
If you are not giving no of reducers then the default no of reducer that run is one.

You can set no of reducers using **job.setNumReduceTasks(__)** and if you are using ToolRunner you can set no of reducers through command line itself.
 **-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=4**